# Java and dom (org.dom4j)

Tags: java, xml, dom, dom4j

I am using some library: org.dom4j. I am beginer in JAVA. I want to know how get all childs in Node Books (i have sections, author in other info (not the some in all books node))

```
java.util.List BookList  = xmlDocument.selectNodes("/BooksList/Books");
Iterator Biterator = BookList .iterator();
while(Biterator.hasNext()){
    Element book = null;
    book = (Element)Biterator.next();
}
```

XML:

```
<BooksList>
    <Books name="Three kingdom">
        <author name="Title">
        <sections  number="216">
    </Books>
    <Books name="Frog and king">
        <author name="Title s">
        <sections  number="21">
        <pages number="421">
    <Books>
 </BooksList>
```

Comment: Looks like you have some unclosed tags in your XML. Specifically `<author>`, `<sections>`, and `<pages>`.

Comment: Also, the last `<Books>` tag should be probably be a closing tag, not an opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
List books = element.getChildren("Books");
```

Maybe this helps:

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChildren(java.lang.String)

http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch14s08.html